# How to fix on Laravel, Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a shared form that I am using to save or update a post record. I am using `optional($post)->postimage` to check if this variable exists in case of update (because I must display it to let users delete if they want it).
I added a new column which is in hasOne relationship with my main model I am saving data.
I get this error:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
```

and laravel is targeting the line where I have

```
@if (optional($post)->postimage != null)
    ...
```

If I comment this line, my form works perfect as before. But I don't want it like that, because there are existing posts and I want to let users add this data if they want it, like they can add to new record.
I have many existing other relations on my model, including hasOne before the new one I added.
Here is my model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    ...
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class, 'id', 'illustration_img');
    }

    public function postimage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class, 'id', 'cover');
    }
    ...
}
```

What is the problem? what am I doing wrong? How to fix this ? thanks

Comment: Can you share your model code as well (the part that this line of code calls)

Comment: I added model code. thanks